# Is there a way to write out the results of ":ls" to a file?

Tags: command-line, save, buffers

I have a bunch of splits up right now, and it took me a while to find these files (basically I'm chasing down a bug through 50 interconnected files).

Is there a command like `:ls > /tmp/filelist` that will write out the current splits/buffers that I have open to a file?

Comment: I initially misread your question but I believe this is what you're looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573021/how-to-redirect-ex-command-output-into-current-buffer-or-file

Comment: Is this what you want: [How to save window, split, and buffer layout](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/287/51)? Or do you *only* want the list of bufffers?

Comment: @jmathew that's exactly what I was looking for. I never knew about the redir function, this is very useful

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may try the following 3 commands:

```
:redir > filelist.txt | :ls | :redir END
```

> `redi[r][!] > {file}` Redirect messages to file `{file}`. The messages which
>                           are the output of commands are written to that file,
>                           until redirection ends.
>
> To stop the messages and commands from being echoed to the screen, put the commands in a function and call it with `:silent call Function()`. An alternative is to use the `verbosefile` option, this can be used in combination with `:redir`. The difference with `:redir` is that verbose messages are not displayed when `verbosefile` is set.

See: `:help redir`.