# Remember previous session

Tags: sessions

Editors like Sublime Text remember your session, so that whenever you open Sublime Text it is exactly how it was when you last closed it:

- All of the same files are open
- Your cursor is in the same position
- Sublime Text even remembers changes to unsaved files

Can I get the same behavior in vim?

Comment: Have a look at `:h mksession` to start :)

Comment: Probably a dupe of [How to save window, split, and buffer layout?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/287/51)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: You're right, I didn't remember the question existed.

Comment: Looks like that question covers the first two points, but I'm yet to find anything that covers the last one (remember changes to unsaved files)

Comment: Help: :h 'undofile' and :h undo-persistence. You might want to read the following section of vim-galore as well: https://github.com/mhinz/vim-galore#handling-backup-swap-undo-and-viminfo-files

Comment: @lsrdg But how to know which files need undo when all open buffers are saved? Session should store the "unsaved" state of the buffers too.

Answer (score 12):

Vim has a built-in session mechanism, from [`:h session`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#Session):

> A Session keeps the Views for all windows, plus the global settings.  You can
> save a Session and when you restore it later the window layout looks the same.
> You can use a Session to quickly switch between different projects,
> automatically loading the files you were last working on in that project.

It should fill your 2 first requirements but the third one `Sublime Text even remembers changes to unsaved files` isn't supported out of the box.

To save your sessions you need to use `:mksession` ([`:h :mksession`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#%3Amksession)). By default the command will save the file in `./Session.vim` but you can provide a file path as argument (e.g. `:mksession! ~/.Session.vim`)

You can also modify the default behavior with `sessionoptions` ([`:h 'sessionoptions'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27sessionoptions%27)).

To reload your session use `:source ~/.Session.vim` (or whatever filepath you used with `:mksession`).

Note that you need Vim to be compiled with the `+mksession` feature to use the sessions.

---

Finally to automate the process you can add this to your vimrc:

```
" Automatically save the session when leaving Vim
autocmd! VimLeave * mksession
" Automatically load the session when entering vim
autocmd! VimEnter * source ~/Session.vim
```

**Edit 7 years later**

As mentioned in the comments it might be better not to use the `VimEnter` autocommand and trigger the sourcing manually to avoid sourcing the session in situations you don't want.

Or you could make the autocmd a bit smarted and source the session file only when you are in a specific directory.

Or you could have a shell alias like `alias lvim='vim -S ~/Session.vim'` to start a session only when you want to. (That's the solution I ended up using in the long term)

Comment: got to be careful adding this to vimrc as a) you probably won't always open vim from ~, and b) if Session.vim doesn't exist, this will cause error.

Comment: Your answer is not entirely correct, probably because you changed your `~/.vimrc` a long time ago: Session files are stored in `./Session.vim` by default (at least that was the default setting in my case and I didn't change any settings)

Comment: Yes, the directory needs updating. I had to change `autocmd! VimLeave * mksession` to `autocmd! VimLeave * mksession! ~/Session.vim` (note the `!` for overwriting).

Comment: I however highly recommend _not_ adding it to auto-load on `VimEnter`. It might have unpleasant side effects. Whenever I did a `git commit`, it opened my session instead of the commit message file! I've been using it fine just by manually loading it, like so `vim -S ~/Session.vim`.