# How to get the previous session every time I start vim?

Tags: vimrc

Say I have a couple of .py files open in vim.
How do I ensure that the previous setup will be opened as it is every time I start vim(**Just like VS code**).

Comment: related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7867/5298, marked dupe of https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/287/5298

Answer (score 6):

The other answer recommends using sessions, which is correct, but I’m not a huge fan of blindly always creating them and restoring them. Sometimes I don’t want that, and then this would get in my way.

Instead, I recommend one of two approaches:

1. Manually run `:mksession` when you want one; or,
2. Install tpope’s Obsession plugin, and tun `:Obsession`.

With either one, you can jump into the session with `vim -S sessionfile.vim`. Since both the vim commands and the `-S` option default to the name `Session.vim`, there’s very little typing (`vim -S` is usually enough).

The big things Obsession provides are

- only storing sane things in the session, and
- automatically keeping the session file up-to-date

Answer (score 3):

Found 3 answers-
1) Place these in your ~/.vimrc to write and load sessions with F2, F3

```
map <F2> :mksession! ~/vim_session <cr> " Quick write session with F2
map <F3> :source ~/vim_session <cr>     " And load session with F3
```

[1st](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416572/vi-vim-restore-opened-files)

2) Put this in your ~/.vimrc to automate the process

```
" Automatically save the session when leaving Vim
autocmd! VimLeave * mksession
" Automatically load the session when entering vim
autocmd! VimEnter * source ~/Session.vim
```

[2nd](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7867/remember-previous-session)(though this requires ~/Session.vim)

3)More information
[3rd](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html?#session-file)

Comment: Best would be to put info from the links (such as for 3) directly in the post as well.

Answer (score 2):

Currently I use the following approach which I find both compact and flexible:

```
augroup vimStartup | au!
    " ... other stuff here
    " save session on exit (:h v:this_session)
    autocmd VimLeavePre *
        \   if !empty(v:this_session)
        \ |     execute 'mksession!' v:this_session
        \ | endif
augroup end
```

So if using `vim -S` or `nvim "+so ~/Session.vim"` to start then the session will be both loaded and saved. Otherwise nothing will happen. "To start tracking" session manually simply use `:so ~/Session.vim` or `:mks!` anytime. Then "stop tracking" session with `:let v:this_session = ''` etc.

So far I found no use in installing an extra plugin for session management.